# how to flip card in javascript memory game

Tags: javascript

im a begginer in javascript and im trying to flip a card when i click on it.  im passing the cardid in the html when calling the function flipcard. but im getting an error saying cannot set property src of null.

```
var faces = []; //array to store card images
     faces[0] = 'images/king-of-diamonds.png';
     faces[1] = 'images/king-of-hearts.png';
     faces[2] = 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png';
     faces[3] = 'images/queen-of-hearts.png';

var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function() {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
          console.log("You found a match!");
        } else {
            console.log("Sorry, try again.");
        }
}

var flipCard = function(cardId) {

    document.getElementById('q').src=faces[cardId]

    checkForMatch();
}






 Html



  <div>
            <img onclick="flipCard(1)" id="image1" src="images/back.png" alt="Queen of Diamonds">
            <img onclick="flipCard(2)" id="image2" src="images/back.png" alt="Queen of Hearts">
            <img id="image3" src="images/back.png" alt="King of Diamonds">
            <img id="image4" src="images/back.png" alt="King of Hearts">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your code what is id=q?

```
document.getElementById('q').src=faces[cardId]
```

you do not have such an id in your HTML, that is why your src is null

Comment: omg thanks so much !  im so stupid for not seeing this very small error!!

Comment: small errors usually crash good programs. next time you will see it yourself!

Comment: so now that i can flip 1 card how do i get it to flip other cards to there value

Comment: document.getElementById(name).src=faces[cardId]